# How taxing would a game map grid be to a web browser?

Tags: performance, browser, dictionary

Suppose we're making a strategy game (think Civilization) in a web browser. The game has a visible map portion - say 30x30 squares. Each square is 30x30px and has several overlaid images - the terrain, resources, units, roads, etc. The classical way of drawing this would be with a huge `<table>` where each cell would contain absolutely positioned images. It would probably be rendered in Javascript to reduce traffic. But it's still several thousand images and a huge table.

Can the browser take it? Will the performance not drop below any acceptable limits? Alternatively I could keep a pre-rendered map image with as many overlays as possible, but that would be more work, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You should really look into using the [canvas element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element) which does not require the browser to store and compute the whole layout and other DOM stuff.

That being said, a modern browser on a high-performance workstation can display hundreds of images at the same time as demonstrated with the [FishIETank](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/FishIETank/). However, many devices - ranging from smart phones to old PCs - can not. Oh, and using a table is probably slower than a div with `position:relative;` or `absolute` and `absolute`ly images therein.

Comment: Well, I'll still need a grid itself to be drawn, hence the table. Although I suppose it could be part of the terrain images. Or maybe I could have 1px space between the pictures and a background. Hmm, yes, I think that would work well and reduce the load. As for mobile the devices - the interface is so rich that there is no hope whatsoever for mobile devices to run it. Hence they're not even in the intended target audience.

Comment: @Vilx Why can't you use canvas?

Comment: Because I haven't used it before and there are users with older browsers too. But I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at online games like grepolis, they already do some sort of a grid like game, and modern browsers can take this easily.